# Where's my stderr going?

Tags: bash, cron

I have a bash script that includes the command:
    `mv old.txt new.txt`

Old.txt doesn't exist, so when I run the script from the commandline, it gives me the message:
    ``` mv: cannot stat ``test1.txt': No such file or directory ```

If I call the script from cron, however, and try to redirect stderr and stdout to a log file, I end up with a completely blank log (this is done as root in this case, but I still have this problem when it's set in my user crontab).

Crontab entry:
    `# m h  dom mon dow   command`
`0 * * * * /home/beekguk/scripts/test.sh 2>&1 >> /home/beekguk/logs/test.log`

So - where's stderr going in this case? Does it just disappear? I've seen on various forums that it gets mailed to root, but I'm not sure what that means or how to find it.

I know just enough about Linux and bash to get me in hot water, and I have a feeling this one may end up with me smacking my forehead and going "Doh!", but thought I'd give it a try anyway.

Edit: I got around this by correcting the redirection on my crontab entry:
    `0 * * * * /home/beekguk/scripts/test.sh >> /home/beekguk/logs/test.log 2>&1`
... but I'm still curious about where these messages would go if I forgot to redirect them!

For anyone reading this in the future: note that I accepted the answer equally for the helpful comment thread.

Comment: In some unix distros, the output of whatever is ran from cron ends up in `/var/log/syslog` (or something similar). Check that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your redirections reversed.  Standard error is therefore going to the cron job's standard output, which is normally mailed to whoever owns the job.

Comment: Ok, so that takes care of the "Doh!" part. But, as far as "normally mailed to whoever owns the job" goes ... I don't have MAILTO set in the crontab (and I don't think I have sendmail/postfix/whatever's required for that to work set up anyway). Where's this mail going?

Comment: The order of processing is left-to-right, so `2>&1` results in `stderr` being sent to cron's copy of `stdout`, and then `>>file.log` reassigns stdout to the file.  In the meantime, `stderr` is still going to the original `stdout`.

Comment: It's being delivered to the user running the cron.  And if that can't be delivered, it's being sent to cron (which usually redirects to root).  And if that can't be delivered, it is dropped on the floor.

Comment: Good question.  You may be able to get some information from `/var/log/messages`.  And without `MAILTO` set, it will use the user that is running the job (if you're using the global `crontab` or the `run-parts` stuff, it would be `root`).  I would be inclined to guess, in the absence of other setup, that there are messages piling up in `/var/mail/root` or `/var/spool/mail/root`.

Comment: `/var/log/syslog` on my system (xUbuntu)

Comment: @geekosaur - `/var/mail/root` and `var/spool/mail/root` are empty; `/var/log/syslog` records that the cronjob executed, but not the error message itself. Any idea where it would go if I was running this on my user crontab instead of the global one?

Comment: @Andy Finkenstadt - Thanks - got around this by fixing my redirection (but I still don't know where undirected stderr output goes).

Comment: @Beekguk: if it's not in a file named after your username in one of the directories I mentioned earlier, then it got dropped on the floor and you'll need to install an MTA to get it.

Comment: @geekosaur - yeah, I think I'll stop chasing this and just go with that. Thanks!