# cron job not picking up oracle query result

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, environment-variables, cron

I've written a shell script which return the value of variable1 through oracle query result when script execution is being done manually. But when it's done by cron job oracle value of variable1 is empty. It seems cron job not even executing sql query.

**shell script:**

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "test report" >> test.txt


variable1=$(
echo "set feed off
set pages 0
--sql query
exit
"  | sqlplus -s username/Password@dbname
)
echo "count:" "$variable1" >> testreport.txt

cat test.txt | mailx -s "test report"  abc@xyz.com
```

**Cron job:**

```
 * * * * * /scriptdir/abc.sh
```

kindly suggest the right approach.

Comment: Check the logged in user and anything to do with file paths from within the script. Maybe echo the entire list of shell environment variables to a file, as well as `which sqlplus`. Are you capturing stderr output? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397942/wheres-my-stderr-going

Comment: Try to use absolute paths for sqlplus cat mailx